# Can multiple iOS simulators communicate with each other over wifi?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, wifi

I'm working on Ray Wenderlich's "How to make a Simple Playing Card Game with Multiplayer and Bluetooth."

That game can use Wifi when Bluetooth is unavailable.

If I open an iOS simulator on a computer and another iOS simulator on a different computer, will the iOS simulators be able to communicate over wifi?

I believe the answer is yes, since each iOS simulator can send/receive data over wifi.  However, I wanted to check before I find another computer and install XCode on it.

Comment: Yes it's 100% possible, I suggest you to use multi peer connectivity framework. That tutorial is now too OLD

Comment: Thanks @AnandK.  I know the tutorial is old, but I thought there might still be some useful concepts since I'm new to iOS development.  I will look into the multi peer connectivity framework.  If you know of any good tutorials on multi peer connectivity framework, I would appreciate the info.

Comment: Just write 'multipeer connectivity framework' tutorial in google and you will find many tutorial on this